# How to create variable from different time frames in R?

Tags: r

I am wondering how I can create a variable within a pipe that comprises different time frames. For example, I have 4 groups of items, each occurring different frequencies throughout a year. Now, I would like to divide that month's amount by the total amount per group of the entire year. How would I write that?

What I got:

```r
abc <- dataset %>% 
  group_by(group, month) %>%
  summarize(month, TotItemsMonth = ?, TotItemsYear = ?,
            ratio = TotItemsMonth/TotItemsYear)
```

How would I write this? I don't know how to have TotItemsMonth sum months and TotItemsYear sum years within the same segment.

Hope this makes sense!

Thank you for reading.

Comment: It will be easier to help if you can provide a bit of example data as code we can load.

Comment: I'm guessing `dataset %>% count(group, month) %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(TotItemsMonth = n, TotItemsYear = sum(n), ratio = n / sum(n))`

Answer (score 0):

I created this data frame as an example.

```
df1<-tribble(
  ~year, ~month, ~group, ~n,
  #--|--|----|----
  2020, 1, "A", 3,
  2020, 2, "A", 4,
  2020, 3, "A", 3,
  2020, 4, "A", 4,
  2020, 5, "A", 3,
  2020, 6, "A", 4,
  2020, 7, "A", 3,
  2020, 8, "A", 4,
  2020, 9, "A", 3,
  2020, 10, "A", 4,
  2020, 11, "A", 3,
  2020, 12, "A", 4,
  2020, 1, "B", 5,
  2020, 2, "B", 4,
  2020, 3, "B", 3,
  2020, 4, "B", 3,
  2020, 5, "B", 3,
  2020, 6, "B", 4,
  2020, 7, "B", 7,
  2020, 8, "B", 4,
  2020, 9, "B", 10,
  2020, 10, "B", 4,
  2020, 11, "B", 3,
  2020, 12, "B", 4,
  2020, 1, "C", 3,
  2020, 2, "C", 4,
  2020, 3, "C", 3,
  2020, 4, "C", 4,
  2020, 5, "C", 46,
  2020, 6, "C", 4,
  2020, 7, "C", 3,
  2020, 8, "C", 47,
  2020, 9, "C", 3,
  2020, 10, "C", 4,
  2020, 11, "C", 34,
  2020, 12, "C", 4,
  2021, 1, "A", 3,
  2021, 2, "A", 4,
  2021, 3, "A", 33,
  2021, 4, "A", 4,
  2021, 5, "A", 32,
  2021, 6, "A", 4,
  2021, 7, "A", 3,
  2021, 8, "A", 41,
  2021, 9, "A", 3,
  2021, 10, "A", 4,
  2021, 11, "A", 3,
  2021, 12, "A", 4,
  2021, 1, "B", 52,
  2021, 2, "B", 4,
  2021, 3, "B", 3,
  2021, 4, "B", 3,
  2021, 5, "B", 3,
  2021, 6, "B", 43,
  2021, 7, "B", 7,
  2021, 8, "B", 4,
  2021, 9, "B", 10,
  2021, 10, "B", 4,
  2021, 11, "B", 3,
  2021, 12, "B", 4,
  2021, 1, "C", 3,
  2021, 2, "C", 4,
  2021, 3, "C", 34,
  2021, 4, "C", 4,
  2021, 5, "C", 6,
  2021, 6, "C", 4,
  2021, 7, "C", 3,
  2021, 8, "C", 47,
  2021, 9, "C", 3,
  2021, 10, "C", 4,
  2021, 11, "C", 34,
  2021, 12, "C", 4,
)
```

And then I calculated total amount per group of the entire year

```
df2<-df1 %>%
  group_by(group,year)%>%
  summarise(total_year=sum(n))
```

> 

```
df2
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   group [3]
  group  year total_year
  <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>
1 A      2020         42
2 A      2021        138
3 B      2020         54
4 B      2021        140
5 C      2020        159
6 C      2021        150
```

Next, I join df1 and df2 and then calculate the ratio

```
df3<-df1%>%
  left_join(df2, by=c('year'='year', 'group'='group'))%>%
  mutate(ratio = n/total_year)

> df3
# A tibble: 72 × 6
    year month group     n total_year  ratio
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl>      <dbl>  <dbl>
 1  2020     1 A         3         42 0.0714
 2  2020     2 A         4         42 0.0952
 3  2020     3 A         3         42 0.0714
 4  2020     4 A         4         42 0.0952
 5  2020     5 A         3         42 0.0714
 6  2020     6 A         4         42 0.0952
 7  2020     7 A         3         42 0.0714
 8  2020     8 A         4         42 0.0952
 9  2020     9 A         3         42 0.0714
10  2020    10 A         4         42 0.0952
# … with 62 more rows
```

I hope this helps!